# Trouble WIth Immediate Shutdown in Ubuntu 13.10 with Cinnamon

Tags: shutdown, cinnamon

Just installed Ubuntu on my family's computer. I thought the Cinnamon desktop environment would be better for my parents who have only ever used Windows. Everything works great until I try to shut down. Shutting down while in Cinnamon desktop brings up a prompt window that says it will shutdown in 60 seconds and gives the option to either suspend or cancel. The suspend button does not suspend the computer. Allowing the timer to countdown merely logs the current user out.

Under power management, I have selected Shutdown Immediately for Power button action. I still get the same prompt. I have tried toggling between the other options, but regardless of what option is selected, the shutdown button always brings up the suspend or cancel prompt with no way to shutdown immediately.

I would prefer not to use the power button for this as it is partially concealed with the computer desk.

The fastest way to shutdown is to log out (which says it will log out in 60 seconds but also has log out and cancel buttons, so I can immediately log out) and then shutdown. I would prefer to have it automatically shut down.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:
I also cannot suspend using the button to lock screen. This particular keyboard has a dedicated button for it, and the button works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Installing consolekit then shutting down completely and rebooting fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get install consolekit
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Is it still working? Because shortly after, it just stopped connecting to the internet. Seems to work fine with Unity, but I tried installing Cinnamon, LXDE, and KDE, all stopped connecting to wifi after reboot.